# Amplify fails to download object from s3

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am trying to download an object from existing s3 bucket to IOS app using amplify-swift.
I've followed the tutorial to init amplify, and import storage.
I am trying to do a call for an unauthenticated user->
In Cognito console I defined a role for unauth user, (and allowed access to unauth users), gave him permissions to my bucket and verified with simulator that getObject works.
When calling this code:

```
 let key = "images/some_file.txt"
        do {
            try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
            try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSS3StoragePlugin())
            try Amplify.configure()
            
            print("Amplify configured with storage plugin")
        } catch {
            print("Failed to initialize Amplify with \(error)")
        }
    
        
        
       Amplify.Storage.downloadData(
            key: key,
            progressListener: { progress in
                print("Progress: \(progress)")
            }, resultListener: { (event) in
                switch event {
                case let .success(data):
                    print("Completed: \(data)")
                case let .failure(storageError):
                    print("Failed: \(storageError.errorDescription). \(storageError.recoverySuggestion)")
            }
        })
```

I get this error:

> Amplify configured with storage plugin 2021-03-31 18:09:09.988304+0300
> ota[30840:728969] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen
> libquic failed Progress: <NSProgress: 0x6000001d50e0> : Parent: 0x0
> (portion: 0) / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 243 of -1
> Failed: The HTTP response status code is [403].. TODO some status code
> to recovery message mapper. For more information on HTTP status codes,
> take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

I checked that the pool id, bucket name are all defined correctly in the json files.
What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

this seems to work, so i know the actual problem is not with the permissions, but rather with the amplify default download:

```
let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadExpression()
            expression.progressBlock = {(task, progress) in DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                print("Downloading...")
            })
            }
        let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .EUWest1, identityPoolId: "eu-west-1:xxxxxx")
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .EUWest1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
        AWSS3TransferUtility.register(with: configuration!, forKey: "customTU")
        let tu = AWSS3TransferUtility.s3TransferUtility(forKey: "customTU")
        tu?.downloadData(fromBucket: bucket, key: _key, expression: expression) { (task, URL, data, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        print("Got here")
                        let rawJSON = (String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))!
                        print(rawJSON)
                    })
            }
```